# Regex for calcul

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string represents calcul and I want use regex for replace all data start with $.

Exemple :

```
value : $Var1+10*$Var2/$Var3-$Var4
```

I want 4 groups :

```
$Var1 $Var2 $Var3 $Var4
```

I tried this regex :

```
 \$.+?)[+-\/*]
```

It's ok for 3 first group `($Var1 $Var2 $Var3)` but no for `$Var4`. 
It's because `$Var4` is just before end of string and I don't find solution to add "end of string" in my list.

I tried :

```
\$.+?)[+-\/*$] 

\$.+?)[+-\/*\$]
```

but not work.

So I like to have any solution to add "end of string" in my list [].

Thanks,

Charly

Comment: It is a well-known problem, you can't use zero-width assertions inside character classes, they lose their special meaning there. What you can do is an alternation group, or revamp the whole pattern altogether (preferable). `\$.+?)[+-\/*]` could not have worked since 1) there is an unpaired parenthesis, and 2) `-` creates a range, you must put `-` at the start/end of the class or escape it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a regex which gives you the variable names then this would be it:

```
\$Var\d+
```

You don't have to add anything to start searching at the beginning or end of a string. Regex doesn't require this. For your test string "$Var1+10*$Var2/$Var3-$Var4" this will simply return all variable names. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/Qw8JAB/1).

If your variable names don't necessarily contain Var but always start with a dollar sign then you can use the regex below to match them.

```
\$\w+
```

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I want :))